# Windows Phone Application Launch and IsolatedStorage

Tags: windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I have logic which checks and creates the isolated storage directory and the files related to my application.

Do I put this logic within `Application_Launching` method within `App`?

Or shall I simply call this on Page_Load of my starting XAML page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I think that would be great in Application_Launching event. But, take care on exceptions because can crash your app.

My 2 cents.